# role based access control in node js

Tags: node.js, textbox, authorization, role

I am developing a web portal using Angular JS and node.js and I have been researching to find a library in node.js which provides role based access control.

All the libraries  which are currently available such **connect-roles, ACL** etc provide page level authorization where you cannot access a particular path or URL based on your role.

Do we have any ready made options where in we can enable/disable a text box based on the role of the user? So my page page will be rendered to the user however some of the fields will be disabled based on the role of the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one did you finally use ?

Comment: Try https://github.com/onury/accesscontrol

Comment: Also  https://github.com/stalniy/casl

Comment: Also https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl

Answer (score 0):

You could give below a try

[image]
[image]

The above is part of ongoing Node.js boilerplate platform below

[Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify](https://github.com/matt212/Nodejs_Postgresql_VanillaJS_Fastify)